# When PostgreSQL query <Value returns =Values

Tags: postgresql, floating-point

I'm running a query using PostgreSQL 9.6.6 and when querying:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
      threshold_value < VALUE
```

returns all values = VALUE and not < VALUE as it should. In the same way if I query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
      threshold_value = VALUE
```

Shows no values at all when all threshold_value (values) are equal to VALUE (VALUE is 1.4)

My `threshold_value` column is of type `real`. Should this be happening, or is it a known bug? Is this related to conversion errors between the python implementation of PGAdmin and the DB, or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to the floating point arithmetic world ;) Please read: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Well... it's a conversion error. Not an error but rather an interpretation difference. Then, if i want to correctly run the query, should i make a CAST from real to number?

How can i not "pitfall" into something like this in more complex situations?

Comment: You could use `numeric` (in Postgres) and `Decimal` (in Python) if you want accuracy (to a specific or arbitrary hight accuracy). Or use float/real but never test for equality. Only `<` and `<=` and beware that some values, like `1.4` will never be represented exactly as you send them (to Python or Postgres) and make your applications aware.

Answer (score 0):

The fractional part is complex

```
0 * 0.5
1 * 0.25
1 * 0.125
0 * 0.0625
0 * 0.03125
1 * 0.015625
1 * 0.0078125
0 * 0.00390625
0 * 0.001953125
1 * 0.0009765625
1 * 0.00048828125
0 * 0.000244140625
```

I'm stopping but you can keep going...

```
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
```

Now we're going to take all the ones and add them up..

```
1 * 0.25
1 * 0.125
1 * 0.015625
1 * 0.0078125
1 * 0.0009765625
1 * 0.00048828125
```

The result is `0.39990234375`. And, that's the problem here... You can't really write `0.4` in binary. That makes it a floating-point error. That means that the system has a rounding error, and it will try to accommodate for it.

```
   1/3 = 0.3333333333333333
   1/3 = 0.3333333333333333
+  1/3 = 0.3333333333333333
===========================
   3/3 = 1
```

Without which the above wouldn't be possible.